# zooming in a UIScrollView changing the (zoom-scaled) content size

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, uiscrollview

I've got a vertically scrolling scroll view with frame (1000, 500) and contentSize (1000, 1500). This works fine. However, as soon as I zoom in, it crops the content size to whatever I was looking at before the zoom, so, I can't scroll vertically anymore past the original bounds. That is, if I zoom to 2x from the default view, it now reports contentSize as (2000, 1000) instead of the expected (2000, 3000). I can't scroll past that initial (1000, 500) rectangle I was looking at. When I zoom back out to 1x, I *still* can no longer scroll vertically; it changes the contentSize to (1000, 500).

How do I fix this? Can I not combine scrolling and zooming in the same UIScrollView? I tried saving the height before zoom, and then correcting the contentSize in the didEndZooming delegate method (contentSize = (width, savedHeight * scale)), but then it displays all sorts of odd behavior, including jumping around on landing.

Shouldn't this just work out of the box? Am I crazy?

```
- (void)createPage {
    self.fullWidthScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,LANDSCAPE_WIDTH,LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.fullWidthScroller];

    self.fullWidthScroller.contentSize = CGRectMake(0,0,LANDSCAPE_WIDTH,LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT*2);
    self.fullWidthScroller.delegate = self;
    self.fullWidthScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.fullWidthScroller.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    self.fullWidthScroller.bouncesZoom = YES;

    self.container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,LANDSCAPE_WIDTH,LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT)];
    [self.fullWidthScroller addSubview:self.container];

    self.page = [[SinglePageViewStretched alloc] init];
    [self.container addSubview:self.page]; //container gets another view added elsewhere
}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.container;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    NSLog(@"size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(scrollView.contentSize));
    NSLog(@"offset: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
    //scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, self.contentSizeHeight * scale);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to implement zoom? It's perfectly fine to combine UIScrollView and zooming.

Comment: Added the code. It's as simple as it gets.

Comment: And, suddenly, it's working, and I have absolutely no idea why, because I don't think I changed anything.